# How to create an instance of Element/VariableElement/TypeElement in Java

Tags: java, reflection

Is there any way to create an instance of the [VariableElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/VariableElement.html) without resorting to manually overriding all the methods, but rather via some standard library utility class?

Comment: Values of these types are typically provided to you when using APIs like annotation processing. See the javadoc of the package, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/package-summary.html).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The problem is that I am writing tests for the annotation processor, and do not have access to `RoundEnvironment` and have to create them manually. I know I can probably mock it, but it contardicts the principle of "Do not mock objects you do not own".